# Slideshow hangups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a slideshow. I'm following the [w3Schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) for this.

I've got my slides in HTML, like so:

```
<div class="slide fade">
    <img src="assets/home_slide1.png" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="slide fade">
    <img src="assets/home_slide2.png" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

And my slideshow function in js (which is nearly literally copied from the tutorial):

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");//jquery, use $(".slide");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}
```

It's not displaying, and the reason according to my console is:

```
TypeError: slides[(slideIndex - 1)] is undefined
```

because when I debug, **var slides** is never being populated, so **slides[0]** is undefined. What am I missing in my troubleshooting for why this is happening?

Comment: Seems to work? https://jsfiddle.net/fosL4c2y/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem was (and I don't think you could have seen this from the code I posted), I didn't have the call to showSlides() in my document.ready(function{}).

I knew it was something TINY like that, but not experienced enough to know what miniscule thing it was.